# Best way to send a long base64 string to server

Tags: php, android, base64

i'm sending a base64 encoded image in server.
i used to store it in a variable that i'll send in post to the server,
but my server gives me a 503 response status or take time.
what's a best way to send a long string or to compress the value of content to send to the server?

Comment: 503 is a general server error. Check webserver logfiles.

Comment: Internal error on sending request(POST //raw HTTP/1.1); uri(/public/index.php?/raw) content-length(7900243): SendRequest: prepare(): user_get_body(restBodyInFile, 3933536): read from client failed
this is the response of server when the string is to long

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

First Step : convert image to Base64 string

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = getFileStream();
    fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
    return new String(Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Second Step send Request

```
Base64UploadRequest request = new Base64UploadRequest(this, uploadId,  ApiConfig.UPLOAD_HOST + "/raw");
        request.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        request.addHeader("Keep-Alive", "timeout=600, max=100");
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.addParameter("source", base64String());
        request.addParameter("extension", extension);
        request.setNotificationConfig(getNotificationConfig("Envoie des photos"));
        request.setMaxRetries(3);
        request.startUpload();
```

But the server take time when the base64 string is too long

```
get_client_block(102400) failed
Internal error on sending request(POST //raw HTTP/1.1); uri(/public/index.php?/raw) content-length(361157): SendRequest: prepare(): user_get_body(bodyLocalBuf, 102400): read from client failed
```